# React Component controlled <select> dropdown, when I clear filters the select dropdown sets itself back to its default value and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Component that features a set of filters inside of a  dropdown.

The top level option contains a generic "All" message that the user sees before they click the dropdown, and then underneath that I have a set of dynamically generated options.

I also have a "Clear filters" button that, when hit, sets the state of everything back to default including my select dropdown.

Everything works how I want it to, I'm just not sure why. My first thought is that because my top level `<option value={''}>` has a value of an empty string and my hook that sets the initial state for the `<select>` value is also an empty string, the dropdown option is then set based on that, but I'm not sure. Can anyone explain why this works exactly?

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const states = {
  AL: "Alabama",
  AK: "Alaska",
  AZ: "Arizona",
  AR: "Arkansas",
  CA: "California",
  CO: "Colorado"
};

type Props = {
  onFilterClear: Function;
  onFilterChange: Function;
  locations: Location[];
};

export const LocationFilter = (props: Props) => {
  const [statuses, setStatuses] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [state, setState] = useState<string>('');

  const handleStateChange = e => {
    setState(e.target.value);
    props.onFilterChange(statuses, state)
  };

  const handleFiltersClear = () => {
    setStatuses([]);
    setState('');
    props.onFilterClear(statuses, state)
  };

  let activeStates = props.locations.map(x => ({abbr: x.address.state, name: states[x.address.state]}));


  return (
    <FilterContainer>
      <Container fluid={true}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div>FILTER BY STATE</div>
            <select value={state} onChange={handleStateChange}>
            <option value={''}>All</option>
              {activeStates.map((state) => (
                <option value={state.abbr} key={state.abbr}>{state.name}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <button onClick={handleFiltersClear}>CLEAR FILTERS</button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </FilterContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: That's exactly what's going on - `setState('')` makes `state` the empty string, therefore the select gets that as a value, so the selected option becomes the one with `value=''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question and then received validation from @RobinZigmond (thank you!)